# Unable to pass the variable in __redirect in new form for list SharePoint Designer

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, redirect, newform

I want user to redirect to the different page after creating new list item. To achieve this, I have created custom new form using SharePoint designer.

My code in Custom New Form is as below:

```
<xsl:variable name="CustomURL">
    <xsl:value-of select="http://www.gmail.com"></xsl:value-of>
</xsl:variable>
<input type="button" value="Save">
    <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
      <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent(concat('__commit;__redirect={',$CustomURL,'}'))"/>
    </xsl:attribute>                                           
</input>
```

However I am not able to go the page, i.e. `http://www.gmail.com`.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

try using the below change:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent(concat('__commit;__redirect='+'{$CustomURL}')
```